# Few theoretical questions on gaussian process with basic example

Tags: gaussian-process

I am trying to understand Gaussian process. and I am stucked now.

[image]

This above notation is what data(n by 2) looks like in my head.

[image]

[image]

And These are from this lecture by Marc Deisenroth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdCXdUzLfao&t=2753s

I was trying to implementing Exponentiated qurdratic function from the scratch.

I am now confused what x_i and x_j are. <- My first question

So the distance(x_i, x_j) is like distance(x11 , x12)  or distance(y1, y2) in my notation?

Is f(x) same as Y ? <- Second question

f(w1*x11 + w2*x12) is same as y1 in my head now. However, f() is unknown from the prior.

I've seen lots of gaussian process lectures on Youtube, but I really can't get it.
What I know are

- GP try to find the distribution over functions instead of parameters(bayesian linear regression)
- Kernel function is the key. (optimizing hyperparameters in kernel)
- Kernel function should be n by n matrix. (with n obsevations)

My brain is melting...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of your $\mathbf{X}$ matrix and $\kappa(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = \kappa([x_{i1}, x_{i2}] - [x_{j1}, x_{j2}])$

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you very much!!